# Is it possible to infer indirect relationships in Sparx EA?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have three components, A, B and C, and I associate A to B and B to C. If I create a new diagram and drop these three components onto the diagram, EA automatically shows the relationships between the components.

If I only drop A and C on a new diagram, is there a way to get EA to show that A is associated to C without creating an explicit association between A and C?

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly. Add some examples/codes, expected outputs/actual outputs and things you have tried. The easier it is to understand your question, the better luck you will have getting a useful answer.

Comment: I also have this need. In my case it has to do with creating a simplified view of a complex model. The original model may have multiple classes, and alternative paths connecting two classes (A and C), but in the view (e.g. targeted at a someone not have a deep understanding of the details in the model) these alternative paths are sufficiently represented by UML associations (preferably having some specific notation indicating that it is a automatically derived by Sparx EA based on the underlying model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this is not a default behavior in EA, and some EA practitioners even argue against such a request.

I've seen one of my client in a similar situation, where there was a need to traverse from a business process to use cases without adding the requirements on to the picture (Their usual hierarchy business process -> Requirements -> UCs)
We ended up automating trace connectors creation in this particular instance. Where everytime a requirement is linked to a usecase, and if the same requirement is linked to a business process, a trace relationship is created between UC & BP.

NB - This could end up in really messy relationships, if you don't constraint it for specific purpose

Answer (score 0):

The Associations A->B and B->C imply nothing about any potential relationship between A and C. For example, if the Association between B->C defines that B has a private attribute of type C, then A may not even know that C exists. Creating an explicit relationship is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

To what the other posters have said, I'll add that implicit relationships are simply not part of UML. So I don't see EA supporting it any time soon. If you really need it, Nizam Mohamed's automation suggestion will work but you can't get EA to do it out of the box.

If it's enough to see these implicit relationships on demand, you can use EA's Traceability window (under the View menu). This lets you follow relationships between elements in a tree view, so you can navigate from A to B to C.